# How to select the class rel with HTMLAgility

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

```
<div id="id_language" class="sBody text select_m" rel="1">Français</div>
```

From this HTML code. I want HTMLAgility or something else to find it.

And next is my code

```
 while (htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("Français") == null)
                {
                    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id_language").Focus();

                    SendKeys.Send("{DOWN}");
                }
```

In my code, I want to find to keydown until it found  "Français" (or rel=1) and then stop. Anyone can help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So First Francais is the value of your div node. If you want to search for the div Html Node with value Francais. You should have.

```
var divNode = htmldoc.DocumentNode.Descendants().
                       Where(x => x.Name == "div" && x.InnerText == "Français").
                       FirstOrDefault();
```

If you want to find the div with attribute rel=1, you should have something like this:

```
var divNode = htmldoc.DocumentNode.Descendants().
                   Where(x => x.Name == "div" && x.Attributes["rel"].Value == "1").
                   FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It's always display nullException. I think it's because it's doesn't have from the first time. but I got to select it untill it appear. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @KanasawaRamirez Can you give **small** string of the html which produces the exception.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
var french = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@rel]")
var relVal = french.Attributes["rel"].Value;
```

so you can do

```
while(htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@rel]").Attributes["rel"].Value == "1")
{
    SendKeys.Send("{DOWN}");
}
```